# How can I retrieve the ID of the inserted row using ExecuteScalar function and the SCOPE_IDENTITY() function

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I need to be able to get the ID (so I can then pass it through an Add News query) of the inserted row for my image upload table, so I can `INNER JOIN` a news item to it.

According to my research I need to use `ExecuteScalar` function and the `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` function.

Any suggestions on how I can achieve this will be greatly appreciated.

```
 protected void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     if (FileUpload1.PostedFile != null)
     {
         SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString);

         string strQuery = "insert into tblFiles (FileName, FilePath) 
             values(@FileName, @FilePath)"

         SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strQuery);
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FileName", FileName);
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FilePath", "/images/admin/news/" + FileName);  
         cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
         cmd.Connection = con;

         try {
             con.Open();
             cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
         }
         finally {
             con.Close();
             con.Dispose();
         }
     }
 }
```

Once I have the ID I can do another SQL query to insert the news item, with the correct pic ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First things first you need to use Store Procedures instead of just writing your SQL statements inside your application.

Second what you want is to run `SCOPE_IDENTITY` as part of your insert statement like

```
  INSERT INTO tblFiles (FileName, FilePath) 
         VALUE(@FileName, @FilePath);

  SELECT  SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

And then change the execution statement in .NET to **`ExecuteScalar`**

```
var result = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm very new to programming however, hence why I'm writing them inside my application. Can I ask you to link me please a good resource for learning about Stored Procedures?

Comment: Check the example at the end https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Check this simple walkthrough of Creating SPs and using them in .NET http://net-informations.com/csprj/data-providers/cs-stored-procedures.htm

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: How do I pass the SCOPE_IDENTITY to an int to use in my second query to add the correct picID to the news story insert?

Comment: `SELECT CAST(scope_identity() AS int)`